# How to move button on right using flex model?

Tags: html, css

I want to move button at the end of right . Here is my code [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/yoqivareri/edit?html,output)

```
    <div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
       <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Back</h3>
        <div style="display: flex">
         <button class="btn btn-primary clearfix" ng-click="onRejectedReason()">Rejected Reason</button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `margin-left: auto` to your `button` parent.

Answer (score 2):

you can set parent as `display:flex;flex-direction: row` and make `h1` as `flex-basis: 100%;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>

<body>
  <div style=" display: flex;flex-direction: row; align-items: center;">
    <h3 style=" flex-basis: 100%;">Back</h3>

    <button class="btn btn-primary clearfix" ng-click="onRejectedReason()">Rejected Reason</button>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Solution 2: You can insert a `span` element in between the div which you want to align right by applying `flex: 1 1 auto` .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="display: flex;justify-content:   justify-content: space-between;;">
    <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Back</h3>
    <span style="flex: 1 1 auto;"></span>
    <div style="display: flex">
      <button class="btn btn-primary clearfix" ng-click="onRejectedReason()">Rejected Reason</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think he want's even the h1 on the right. maybe align-content:flex-end can help?

Comment: As per his question I understand that he wants button to be aligned right

Comment: Yeah i read better, and it's right he want the button, sorry :) your answer is good and i upvoted it ;)